# Trouble With hasNext() in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, input, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program that reads pairs of words and outputs the number of pairs of identical words. It's assumed an even number of words are inputted. When I run my code, it doesn't output anything. It appears to be continually running. When I press Ctrl-Z after I'm done inputting words, it either returns "0" or nothing at all. Any thoughts on how to make my program run properly? Thanks.

EDIT: it runs fine in the command prompt, but not in Eclipse.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;

        while (input.hasNext()) { 

            String string1, string2; 
            string1 = input.next();
            string2 = input.next();

            if (string1.equals(string2)) {
                ++counter;  
            }   

        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking `hasNext()` once, but then calling `next()` twice. The second `next()` can fail if there are no more elements.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. How would you suggest fixing this? I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really work in eclipse for me (nor does in netbeans for what i have read), to test if your code actually works well you should do this:
(In windows) Open a command prompt ( execute ... "cmd" + Enter )
then compile your class or classes with

```
javac YourClass.java
```

if no errores it will just let you type a new command with no messages and then

```
java YourClass
```

then you can try the Ctrl + z in windows (ctrl + d in linux)  which will print the ^Z character and then hit enter.

Hope it helped.